# wrong output when deleting rows or columns in a matrix

Tags: python

I have this assignment, where A black and white image can be represented by an array where the values in the
array denote the grey scale level, e.g. white=0, black=1, and grey scales are numbers
between 0 and 1. When an image has a fixed background color, it can be useful to crop the image by removing the outer parts of the image which have constant color.

I want to create a function that takes as input an array representing a black/white image, as well
as a number between 0 and 1 representing the background color. The function must return a cropped image,
where all leading and trailing rows and columns with value equal to the given background color are removed.

I have tried this:

```
def imageCrop(img_in,background):
    for i in range(len(img_in)):
        if np.sum(img_in[i,:])==background:
           img_out= np.delete(img_in,img_in[i,:],axis=1)
        elif np.sum(img_in[-i,:])==background:
            img_out=np.delete(img_in,img_in[-i,:],axis=1)
        elif np.sum(img_in[:,i])==background:
           img_out= np.delete(img_in,img_in[:,i],axis=0)
        elif np.sum(img_in[:,-i])==background:
            img_out=np.delete(img_in,img_in[:,-1])
    return img_out
```

The inputs are:

```
img_in = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0],[0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0.3, 0, 0.3, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
background = (0.0)
```

The output should be:

```
[[1,0,0.5],[0.5,0,0],[0.3,0,0.3]]
```

So each row or column that has the same total sum as the background will be deleted

Right now my output is:

```
[[1,0,0.5,0,0],[0.5,0,0,0,0],[0.3,0,0.3,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: your code is very confused: the `axis` doesn't match the direction, the range you are picking is messed, and sometimes you use `-i` and `-1`. But I believe your main problem is that you are overwriting the same `img_out` variable over and over again: whenever you find a row/column you want to delete, you take the _original array_ and delete some rows. So your result is result of _only one operation_ - the last delete that you found.

Comment: also you're using `np.sum`, which is a sum of the row/column ... and that will only work when background is 0. Because sum of all 1's is not 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can definitely be optimized for speed, but here's an easy fix. It iterates through the rows and columns from both ends of the array/image, and stops once it finds the first row/column that contains pixels, so that it won't delete any inner areas.

EDIT: substituted `np.sum` with `np.all` so that it can work for any background.

```
def imageCrop(img_in,background):
    rows_to_delete = []
    cols_to_delete = []
    n_rows = img_in.shape[0]
    n_cols = img_in.shape[1]

    for i in range(n_rows):
        if np.all(img_in[i, :] == background):
            rows_to_delete.append(i)
        else:
            break

    for i in range(1, n_rows):
        if np.all(img_in[-i, :] == background):
            rows_to_delete.append(n_rows-i)
        else:
            break

    for i in range(n_cols):
        if np.all(img_in[:,i] == background):
            cols_to_delete.append(i)
        else:
            break

    for i in range(1, n_cols):
        if np.all(img_in[:,-i] == background):
            cols_to_delete.append(n_cols-i)
        else:
            break

    img_out = np.delete(img_in, rows_to_delete, axis=0)
    img_out = np.delete(img_out, cols_to_delete, axis=1)

    return img_out
```

**Output:**

```
array([[1. , 0. , 0.5],
       [0.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [0.3, 0. , 0.3]])
```

Otherwise, if you want to remove ALL rows and columns with the same total sum as the background:

```
def imageCrop(img_in,background):
    rows_to_delete = []
    cols_to_delete = []
    n_rows = img_in.shape[0]
    n_cols = img_in.shape[1]

    for i in range(n_rows):
        if np.all(img_in[i, :] == background):
            rows_to_delete.append(i)

    for i in range(n_cols):
        if np.all(img_in[:,i] == background):
            cols_to_delete.append(i)

    img_out = np.delete(img_in, rows_to_delete, axis=0)
    img_out = np.delete(img_out, cols_to_delete, axis=1)

    return img_out
```

**Output**

```
array([[1. , 0.5],
       [0.5, 0. ],
       [0.3, 0.3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `list`:

```
img_in = img_in.tolist()
flag = 1  
while flag != 0 :
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for i in img_in:
        if i[len(i)-1] == background:
            a += 1
        if i[0] == background:
            b += 1
    flag = 0
    for i in img_in:
        if a==len(img_in):
            del i[len(i)-1]
            flag = 1
        if b==len(img_in):
            del i[0]
            flag = 1

for index, i in enumerate(img_in):
    if index == 0 or index == len(img_in) - 1:
         if all(number == background for number in img_in[index]):
             del img_in[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple recursive method. Have used `.all()` so the background can be changed

```
import numpy as np
img_in = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0],[0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0.3, 0, 0.3, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
background = 0.0

def remove_outlines():

    global img_in,background
    if (img_in[0,:]==background).all():
        img_in = np.delete(img_in,0,0)

    elif (img_in[img_in.shape[0]-1,:]==background).all():
        img_in = np.delete(img_in,img_in.shape[0]-1,0)

    elif (img_in[:,0]==background).all():
        img_in = np.delete(img_in,0,1)

    elif (img_in[:,img_in.shape[1]-1]==background).all():
        img_in = np.delete(img_in,img_in.shape[1]-1,1)

    else:
        return
    remove_outlines()

remove_outlines()
```

Output -

```
>>> img_in
array([[ 1. ,  0. ,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.3,  0. ,  0.3]])
```